# Permutations in JSON object

Tags: node.js, json, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

So I'd like to type a part of the code (in Node.js) that would give me all permutations of objects within a JSON object. Each permutation should be unique (two permutations are identical as long as they have exactly the same objects in them, no matter their positions). My JSON object looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "ID": "5465464",
   "e-mail": "something@gmail.com",
   "name": "John"
 },
 {
   "ID": "5433364",
   "e-mail": "something2@gmail.com",
   "name": "Nick"
 },
 {
   "ID": "5465244",
   "e-mail": "something3@gmail.com",
   "name": "George"
 },
 {
   "ID": "5464874",
   "e-mail": "something4@gmail.com",
   "name": "Rick"
 },
 {
   "ID": "5442164",
   "e-mail": "something5@gmail.com",
   "name": "Wayne"
 }
]
```

So the output should basically give me all possible combinations of all objects (3 objects per combination), and it should look something like this:

```
[
    "PERMUTATION1":[
        {
           "ID": "5465464",
           "e-mail": "something@gmail.com",
           "name": "John"
         },
         {
           "ID": "5433364",
           "e-mail": "something2@gmail.com",
           "name": "Nick"
         },
         {
           "ID": "5465244",
           "e-mail": "something3@gmail.com",
           "name": "George"
         }
    ],
    "PERMUTATION2":[
        {
           "ID": "5465464",
           "e-mail": "something@gmail.com",
           "name": "John"
         },
         {
           "ID": "5464874",
           "e-mail": "something4@gmail.com",
           "name": "Rick"
         },
         {
           "ID": "5465244",
           "e-mail": "something3@gmail.com",
           "name": "George"
         }
    ],
    "PERMUTATION3":[
        {
           "ID": "5465464",
           "e-mail": "something@gmail.com",
           "name": "John"
         },
        {
           "ID": "5465464",
           "e-mail": "something@gmail.com",
           "name": "John"
        },
        {
           "ID": "5465464",
           "e-mail": "something@gmail.com",
           "name": "John"
        }
    ],...
]
```

Note that one object can appear multiple times (up to 3) in a PERMUTATION, but two different permutations can't have exactly the same elements in them (position of elements don't matter). I've tried to tackle this problem with bubble sort and different other sorting algorithms, but so far with no success. If you have any ideas how to make this happen please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've tackled this problem by using this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics (js-combinatorics), and I've used bigCombination. I know it's not the best solution, but it works just fine.